# Docker data volumes and scaling in a distributed system

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, azure-virtual-machine, boot2docker

Docker data volumes is living within the host or boot2docker on the local VM(boot2docker).

Having big data from mongoDB running in a data container and mongoDB in another seems to be the way. Will this scale on Google Cloud Engine or Azure Virtuel Machines or other. I mean if all this is running within ONE Virtuel Machine, like boot2docker or other in the cloud. Normally you would scale VM's by creating new instances of VM's but how is this possible with Docker?

Sorry to ask this on StackExchange, but there is no category on dba - but StackExchange has a Category for Docker.

Thanks

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production you would have a large number of (virtual) machines each running docker. To scale mongodb you would have multiple pairs of {mongodb, mongodb-data} containers, where each pair is running on the same machine (required for sharing volumes).

The problems you need to solve:

1) configuring mongodb in a way that makes sense for scaling purposes (sharding, replica pools ,etc)

2) firewall permissions, ip addresses, ports etc to allow docker containers to talk to eachother across hosts.

Docker doesn't solve 1) for you because its application specific. Mongodb will have a different way of doing this than say, couchbase. 2) is not solved by Docker *yet* but I think it might someday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rancher to solve 2., as it automatically manage IP addresses using IpSec private network. I guess kubernetes also solve problem no. 2.